# How to pass constant font size data from one Widget to another in Flutter

Tags: flutter

The [`TextStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html) class in Flutter requires `fontSize` to be constant.

Let's say I already created the constant value in widget `A`. Now I want to pass the value to widget `B` and inside `B` I want to use that like following:

```
const textStyleInB = TextStyle(fontSize: this.iconWidth);
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The TextStyle class in Flutter requires fontSize to be constant.

No, it doesn't.

```
final textStyleInB = TextStyle(fontSize: this.iconWidth);
```

Now, if you want things to be `const` (so, a *compile time* constant, instead of `final`, a run time constant), then yes, you cannot have a variable for that that is set at runtime. Obviously, a compile time constant can only be set at compile time.

Comment: but the user wants to pass it from Widget `A` to Widget `B`

Comment: If *the user* wants to pass it from A to B, then by definition, it *cannot* be a **compile-time** constant. Can you explain what your problem is in using a regular, non-const variable?

Comment: Got it. I need to convert the `const textStyleInB` to `final textStyleInB`.

Comment: @nvoigt that's true , I wasn't able to understand this question

Comment: @anirudh To be clear I just want to reuse the value prepared in parent widget. Coming from React/JS I missed the variable type part.

Comment: @nvoigt can I connect with you over linkedin?

Comment: I'm not using Linkedin, sorry.

Comment: @nvoigt can we connect somewhere , need to seek some guidance

Comment: Sorry, I don't do personal mentoring, but if you ask a question here I'm sure you will get an answer by experts, even if it's not me personally.